# animating div fullscreen div overlay with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a fullscreen div overlay that is hidden by setting it's position to fixed and having it top:-100%.  I'd like to to slide down to be a fullscreen overlay, I'm trying to do this with jquery using the .animate.  I have a fiddle but can't seem to get it to work, any help I can get with this would be great, thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/5zZGv/2/

Answer (score 0):

messed around with it some more and got it, http://jsfiddle.net/5zZGv/3/

$("#go").click(function(){
  $("#fullscreen").animate({
    top: '0px',
    height:'100%',
  }, 1500 );
});